# Creating an `object` tag with `createElement` returns a function instead of an object

Tags: javascript, dom

Could someone explain why I am getting different types when creating different elements?

```
typeof document.createElement('div')
"object"
typeof document.createElement('span')
"object"
typeof document.createElement('embed')
"function"
typeof document.createElement('object')
"function"
```

These are on firefox:

```
$ firefox --version

(process:9436): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size == 0' failed
Mozilla Firefox 32.0.3
```

Comment: Because they are callable, and/or due to a bug, and/or for backwards-compatibility. Full details: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=268945

Comment: For what it's worth, both Chrome and IE return `object`.

Comment: I wouldn't trust ECMAScript operators/methods on objects that aren't specifically described in the spec. I'd rather use the data that host objects provide in their respective specifications, like checking a `.nodeType` property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ES5 spec [states](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.3) that an object that implements `[[Call]]` must be reported as `typeof` `"function"`.

A small handful of DOM elements (`object`, `embed`, not many others) *are* callable / do implement `[[Call]]`. This is likely for historical reasons, but the fact remains that you *can* call them.

So Firefox is technically correct in reporting them as `function`s. You could, in fact, argue that Chrome et al. are wrong (if sticking strictly to the ES5 spec) to report them as `object`s, since they are callable in those browsers too. On the other hand, those browsers are doing what most people would probably 'expect'.

More details are in [Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=268945).